# In Android , how to Run background thread code in main thread and get value returned?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, thread-safety, android-handler

We can use handler to run a piece of code on main thread if it was called from a background thread like :

```
 new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                  myMethod(); //this will run on main thread
                } 

            });
```

Q1 : So, if `myMethod()` is returning some value, then how can we get that ( since we cannot get any return value from `run()` method )  ?

Q2 : Is there any way to run code on main thread using `AsyncTask` ? We know that `onPostExecute()` is called on main thread. But can we return anything from asynctask after executing it on `onPostExecute()` ?

Comment: You can register a listener in the main thread to set return value from the background thread.

Comment: which type of data return from myMethod() ? @andro_abc ?

Comment: @jigs "string"...myMethod() will create a string in main thread and it will return it .

Comment: now tell me ,you want your data return form that method ,right ? if so , no need to run your code in main thread ,let me post the solution .

Comment: You can update the UI thread with progress using an AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...)

Comment: @Jigs /@fractalwrench ....yes i can do it in background thread..but all data collection process we are running on main thread only.After data is collected, we are resetting all values. So we must collect it on main thread (For synchronization between data collection and data reset )

Answer (score 0):

Apply this and let me inform if you are getting your data or not ?

Create one application class .

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
//set activity context here , so it can accessible any where 
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext(); 
    }    
    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

now what you have to do is just store your data which is return from that method in to preferences inside handler , like ..

```
MySharedPref pref= new MySharedPref(MyApplication.getAppContext());
pref.saveImei("DATA", ""+data);
```

and make sure one thing , register your application class inside manifiest .

```
<application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">    
</application>
```

Comment: how can you notify Application class if shared Pref is updated ?

Comment: notify your application class means ?? no need to notify that class, it will update existing data when ever we store it preference again with the same preference key.

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private class getNetData extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Object> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //here u can use the handler to post notification / data to the main ui thread 
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                }
            });

        }

        protected Object doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //this runs the back task on main thread
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            //this runs the data aft the back ground task
        }
    }
```

chk this for runnin the bg task on the ui thread

Comment: how can we get the value after running the task in main thread ?

Comment: on post execute you can get the values that you are processing in the doInBackground() function. which you will only get if you return the values from the doInBackground() function aft the completion of the relevant task

Comment: thats y we are using the strict policy to run it on the main thread